# Random Movement of a Character in a matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

Im trying to create a program that shows a character matrix 10x10, and shows a character in it, and in every 600 miliseconds the character would move randomly. But my problem is that everytime i run the program, it is the same movement.

If you look at the function Random_move i used the function Rand()... i also tried with srand(time(null)); before, but that only makes both characters, a and b, to move always in the same direction. Can someone please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

class mapa
{
    private :
    char map[10][10];
    char background[10][10];
    public :
    mapa();
    void cpy_btom();
    void copy_to_map(int, int, char);
    void print();
};
class character
{
    private :
    int posx;
    int posy;
    char type;
    public :
    character(char,int,int);
    void send_print(mapa &);
    void random_move(mapa &);
    void delay(int);
};

int main()
{
    character C1('A', 5, 5);
    character C2('B', 8, 2);
    mapa Mapa;
    while(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        Mapa.print();

        C1.delay(750);

        C1.random_move(Mapa);
        C2.random_move(Mapa);
    }
}

void mapa :: cpy_btom()
{
    for(int a = 0;a < 10;a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0;b<10;b++)
        {
            map[a][b] = background[a][b];
        }
    }
}
void mapa :: print()
{
    system("cls");

    for(int a = 0;a<10;a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0;b<10;b++)
        {
            cout << map[a][b];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cpy_btom();
}
character :: character(char kind = 'a', int x = 5, int y = 5)
{
    type = kind;
    posx = x;
    posy = y;
}
void character :: send_print(mapa & mapa)
{
    mapa.copy_to_map(posx, posy, type);
}

void character :: random_move(mapa & MAP)
{

    int a = rand() % 5;
    int b = rand() % 50;
    if(a == 0) //x --
    {
        if(b < 45)
        {
            if(posx > 0)
                posx--;
        }
        else
        {
            if(posx > 1)
            posx = posx - 2;
        }
    }
    else if(a == 1)
    {
        if(b < 45)
        {
            if(posx < 10)
            posx++;

        }
        else
        {
            if(posx < 9)
            posx = posx + 2;
        }
    }
    else if(a == 2)
    {
        if(b < 45)
        {
            if(posy > 0)
            posy--;
        }
        else
        {
            if (posy > 1)
            posy = posy - 2;
        }
    }
    else if(a == 3)
    {
        if(b < 45)
        {
            if(posy < 10)
            posy++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(posy < 9)
            posy = posy + 2;
        }
    }
    send_print(MAP);
}

void character :: delay(int time)
{
    int a = clock();
    int b = clock() + time;
    while(a < b)
    {
        a = clock();
    }
}
mapa :: mapa()
{
    for(int a = 0;a < 10;a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0;b < 10;b++)
        {
            map[a][b] = ' ';
            background[a][b] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void mapa :: copy_to_map(int x, int y, char kind)
{
    map[x][y] = kind;
}
```

Comment: Have you seeded the RNG with `srand(time(NULL));`?

Comment: Oops! You forgot to read the documentation for `rand` before using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling `srand(time(0))` in the beginning of your `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You must only seed once when you start up your program, not every time you call `rand`.

Comment: While this is certainly true neither it applies to the code that have no single `srand` call, nor would that explain the same movement everything the program is run ;-)

Comment: @Michael: It would if the argument to `srand` always followed the same pattern ;) `int i = 0; while (f()) { srand(i++); g(); }`

Comment: The OP said that when they used `srand` then both characters moved in the same direction.  That suggested the call was being done in the movement function, because both characters are moved at essentially the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some context to other answers, `rand` only produces a pseudo-random sequence of values (i.e. where the next number in the sequence has no dependence on the previous). It is completely deterministic and therefore produces the same sequence each time.

In order to get a different sequence each time, you have to 'seed' the random number. Usually this is done by starting the sequence at an offset that you choose. A sensible value for this is a number which will never be the same twice, i.e. the current date / time. This is where `srand(time(0))` comes from.